# Why are we replacing values in leaves in gradient boosting?

Tags: gbm

As far as I understand, we decompose the error function into a Taylor series, find its derivative, set it to zero and get a new optimal final value for the sheet. This is the gradient step in the space of true values, but it is already of the second order. However, what prevented us from initially training our tree to predict this value? Why train the tree to find the derivative of the ensemble error, if then we replace this value with a more accurate one?